# Python if statement conditions

Tags: python

can someone show me how I can add conditons to my code to if file does not exits, it cannot go further however if file exits then they add can? 
This is what I have so far?

```
def students():
  enter = input("Enter text file: ")
  print ("File found") 
  f=open(enter,'a+')
  t=' '.join(f)
  Username = input("Enter Username: ")
  f.write(Username+",")
  password = input("Enter password:")
  f.write(password)
  f.write(t)
  f.write('\n')
  f.close()
```

Comment: Look into the `os` module, you can use that to check whether a path exists.

Comment: How about looking for it yourself?

Comment: No to python, could you shoe me an example please?